# Can you save sort order in SearchKit? What is Compose Search?

Tags: reports, searchkit

I am creating a mail report and I want to sort by Scheduled Date (decending). When I save the search, all looks good, but when I come back to the search or view results, it defaults to sorting by date in the Ascending instead of depending. I assume by default it only sorts whatever is in the first column?

Also - Compose Search button doesn't seem to do anything - what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to add a "display" from the options on the left. In the display you can set the sort order. Then the display, or a form based on it, is what people would access, not the underlying search.

"Compose" is because you might be on a different tab, like the display's tab, and want to get back to the search.